# Multi-layout and Compose key

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have a laptop running ubuntu 18.04 with FR Layout and at work I switch for US layout.

I have set my compose key for years on right-alt and now I have to disable my compose key back on FR layout because I can't do any symbols.

I'm looking for a solution to disable easily my compose key or to set it depending on keyboard's layout, what can you suggest me?

Comment: Another approach would be to use _English (US, intl., with dead keys)_ instead of _English (US)_ and drop the compose key.

Comment: thanks for your reply, tried it for 15 days, and clearly hate the fact that I have to press twice backquote to have one or alt, for example. do you have any other solution? + shortcuts r-alt + , = ç

Comment: Then you may want to try the `English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)` layout, where you access the dead keys through the <AltGr> or <Right Alt> key.